# How can I achieve this theme with AppCompat?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments, android-styles

I am trying to create this theme for one, and just one of my activities:

[image]

Since I am learning how this styles work, and I am now beginning to be aware that we have more different & incompatible ways of styling in android than atoms in the whole universe. So I've tried to learn from this site: http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator

However when I try to apply its theme in my project that is using AppCompat I get the

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

error type.

I am extending from *ActionBarActivity* in my tabbed activity and I don't feel safe going back now (someone suggested extending *Activity* to solve this issue), since in previous posts I was suggested to use AppCompat, and *ActionBarActivity* seems somehow to be AppCompat related.

I've spent all my week googling for solutions and I've came across these problems:

- [The official Android styling documentation is deprecated.](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)
- The code generated by Android Studio is also deprecated in method such as [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setNavigationMode(int)).*
- http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator is deprecated.

---

---

---

**BUT, to the point now, this is what I have at the moment:**

[image]

So, the **only** thing I am not being able to do is

- <s>putting the logo in the top left corner of the screen (in the action bar), in a way that only affects the action bar of this particular activity,</s> (Done)
- make the orange bar showing which tab is selected.

**How can I achieve this in the most simple way?**

This is my values/style.xml file:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="SmartCampusTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/actionbar_bg_color</item>
    </style>

    <style name="GenericProgressIndicator" parent="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:indeterminate">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

My AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="greensmartcampus.eu.smartcampususerfeedbackapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/SmartCampusTheme">
        <!-- Splash screen while connecting to the web-server -->
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home_screen"
            android:parentActivityName=".AbstractPortraitActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="greensmartcampus.eu.smartcampususerfeedbackapp.AbstractPortraitActivity" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- The activity where all actions take place -->
        <activity
            android:name=".ControlActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home_screen"
            android:parentActivityName=".AbstractPortraitActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="greensmartcampus.eu.smartcampususerfeedbackapp.AbstractPortraitActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

---

*Ps. it's funny how the most up-to-date Android Studio generates deprecated code for tabbed activities and then complains about it being deprecated as if it is your fault...

[image]

**Important Note:** I am a huge fan of MVC and a modularity priest (OSGi practitioner). So I would love if all these styling solutions could be all contained in the style and drawing XML files (as they should be if I correctly recall), the layout information is all contained in my layout files and my java files only contain code about behavior. For example I could just show the action bar icon with java through *getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)*, but inserting layout related stuff in java disrupts the MVC pattern. Also, the website that I mention above can create the layout with the icon in the actionbar without using a single java line. I just need to know how can that be done with AppCompat, which apparently is what I am using because other solutions are deprecated.

Comment: With respect to your icon issue, use `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)`, called on your activity. With respect to your tabs, I recommend that you get rid of your current deprecated implementation and switch to something that is supported (e.g., `ViewPager` and a tabbed indicator).

Comment: Isn't there a way to make the icon appear through my style.xml? By using that method I am inserting interface/layout business in the code that should only be concerned with behavior and system state. Thus disrupting the MVC pattern.

Comment: "Isn't there a way to make the icon appear through my style.xml?" -- not that I am aware of. You are welcome to poke through the source code and see if there is an option for this. "Disrupting the MVC pattern" -- Android does not strictly implement MVC, MVP, MVVM, or any particular GUI architecture pattern. "which apparently is what I am using because other solutions are deprecated" -- the native action bar is most definitely not deprecated.

Comment: "Android does not strictly implement MVC, MVP, MVVM, or any particular GUI architecture pattern" | At least they seem to try, otherwise layout and styles would be mixed together just like web technologies were 10 years ago. styles relate to CSS, layouts relate to HTML with a bit of JS, java relates to dynamic content manager (PHP, ASP, ...). | Also, there are plenty tutorials recommending using the MVC pattern, however, they all seem outdated... Well, keep in touch with this thread, maybe someone can answer that for us.

Comment: >> With respect to your icon issue, use getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true), called on your activity <<

Android still doesn't show the icon.

Do I need to add anything more in my style.xml as well?

Comment: I added the lines <item name="android:icon">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
        <item name="android:logo">@drawable/ic_launcher</item> to my style.xml inside the "SmartCampusTheme" style, but still doesn't show up the icon. It seems to be somehow related to the AppCompat.

Comment: Ok, this combination makes the icon appear as I wanted:
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    actionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);